# XSD: Choosing between 2 options with possibility to pick both

Tags: xml, xsd

So can i somehow make code below work? So that there must be Option 1 or Option 2 present in XML and there could be possible to pick both(but you can't have 2 of the Option 1 or Option 2 at the same time)

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Option1" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Option2" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Option1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Option2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    /xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want one of

- Option 1
- Option 2
- Option 1 and Option 2

This is the same as one of

- Option 1 and maybe Option 2
- Option 2

```
<xsd:choice>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Option1" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="Option2" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Option2" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:choice>
```